# How to fix the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing protocol prefix in endpoint ' null'

Tags: java

I am integrating data from our system to third party system through API Call. As third party system accepts data only through API Call and in Standard JSON format, I have designed Integration to extract data that needs to be sent, transform data from XML to JSON format and then sends data to third party system.

when integration is launched, Data extraction and File format transformation is happening as per design,But at delivery point integration is failing with error as **Error creating endpoint :Root Cause: : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing protocol prefix in endpoint ' null'** .

Am not clear on this error, is this error because of the endpoint API url that is configured as endpoint in integration ?? Following is the API Url configured as endpoint which is provided by the third party system vendor.

https://app.verifica.com/api/verify?apikey=XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXTPX-DXXXA-BXXXI-YDXXX-RXXXX.

Following is the XSLT created to extract data from system

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

 xmlns:is= 
 "java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
 xmlns:xdiff="urn:com.workday/esb/xdiff" 
 xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">

 <xsl:param name="CandidateID" />
 <xsl:param name="FirstName" />
 <xsl:param name="LastName" />
 <xsl:param name="email" />

 <xsl:template match="/wd:Candidate">
 <Candidate>
     <Candidate_ID>
         <xsl:value-of select="$CandidateID"></xsl:value-of>
     </Candidate_ID>
     <FirstName>
         <xsl:value-of select="$FirstName"></xsl:value-of>
     </FirstName>       
 LastName>
        <xsl:value-of select="$LastName"></xsl:value-of>
 </LastName>
 <Email>
       <xsl:value-of select="$email"></xsl:value-of>
 </Email>

    </Candidate> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Following is XSD schema created to convert format from xml to JSON

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="SyncData">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="EmployerId" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="ImporterEmail" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="ReportEmail" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Candidates">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Candidate">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="Candidate_ID" type="xsd:string" />     
                  <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element name="Email" type="xsd:string" />
                  </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
```

Following are the XSLT and XSD code that i have writtem to extract and 
 transform data.

Request for any inputs or corrective directions that resolves this issue. And let me know for any additional information if needed on this.

Thanks,
GJR.

Comment: Without any information about your code or the API specifications, it's going to be hard for to find out the problem...

Comment: Can you copy the full stacktrace and copy the code where you send your request,too?